# Error trying to build a class : type or namespace name

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables, session-variables

I'm trying to create a Session class following a block of code from a previous post.
I tried to follow it verbatim, but instead of using Foo, I used my own definition.  When I try to 
build it, I get the following error:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'UserSession' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\VS\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RCF\RCF\Classes\BasePage.cs   10  16  RCF

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RCF.Classes
{
    public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public UserSession CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return (UserSession)Session["UserSessionObject"];
            }
            set
            {
                if (Session["UserSessionObject"] == null)
                {// Instatiate a new one
                    Session["UserSessionObject"] = new UserSession();
                }
                Session["UserSessionObject"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example code I followed:

```
   public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
     public Foo CurrentFoo
            {
                get
                {
                    return (Foo)Session["FooSessionObject"];
                }
                set
                    {
                    if(Session["FooSessionObject"]==null)
                    { //instantiate a new one
                       Session["FooSessionObject"] = new Foo();
                    }
                    Session["FooSessionObject"] = value;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Okay. So show where you defined it. Don't forget to include the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserSession is expecting a class like this.

```
public class UserSession { }
```

I think you are missing something from your example.  Foo or UserSession has to be a fully developed class.

[image]

Comment: I had been using a class called GlobalDataStore to hold bits of user information (userid, name, etc).  And it's worked with all of my previous projects. The only difference in this case is the app and data are in a hosted environment, which I haven't figured out why that would affect anything, but I substituted "UserSession" with "GlobalDataStore" and it compiled fine.  Now I'm off to putting it in place and continue.  Thank you all.